# App for Facebook notification

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I wanted to do app on facebook that can read site like moodle . for example if teacher uploads some assignment on that site , i should get notification.
can any one guid me for this , what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You might check out this moodle [plugins](https://moodle.org/plugins/view/block_notifications)

If the plugins is not what you looking for, then you could consider to code a background application that periodically query the **mdl_assignment** table from moodle database for any new entry, and then send a HTTP request to your Facebook apps for release the notification via Facebook.